# Nginx reverse proxy to an https address behind corporate proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to setup an Nginx reverse proxy to an AWS API Gateway address like `https://12345.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2` behind a corporate proxy.

I tried the following setup to `www.example.com` and it works. But as soon as I add `https` to it like `https://www.example.com` it fails. I add https since my API Gateway address is not accessible without it.

**Current working config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    underscores_in_headers on;
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
        proxy_pass  http://myCorporateProxy.org:8080;
    }
}
```

**What I want to achieve and error I get:**
Redirect all incoming traffic to localhost to be redirected to API Gateway address which looks similar to `https://123456.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/v2/`
When trying following config, I get a 302 temporarily Moved error.
In configuration it would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    underscores_in_headers on;
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header Host https://www.example.com;
        proxy_pass  http://myCorporateProxy.org:8080;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this. To redirect from http to https is a little different.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myCorporateProxy.org www.myCorporateProxy.org;
    return 301 https://myCorporateProxy.org$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution with various setups as follows none of them works. I basically tried the same setup by moving port number to different places. I also tried with and without location / { ... } part.

Answer (score 0):

We use in our corporate environment the Px proxy to make corporate proxy authentication transparent. But that still does not solve the main task at hand.

I did some experimentation as follows:

The proxy communication for accesssing external sites for **http** request is as follows:

```
root@3863da2d8f8a:~# curl --proxy http://host.docker.internal:3129 http://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
---------
> 2024/01/31 16:58:21.588962  length=121 from=0 to=120
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r
Host: google.com\r
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0\r
Accept: */*\r
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r
\r
< 2024/01/31 16:58:21.728618  length=351 from=0 to=350
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r
Location: http://www.google.com/\r
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r
...  <-- removed lines
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.\r
</BODY></HTML>\r
```

The proxy communication for accessing external sites for **https** request is as follows:

```
root@3863da2d8f8a:~# curl --proxy http://host.docker.internal:3129 https://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
---------
> 2024/01/31 16:58:27.262850  length=112 from=0 to=111
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r
Host: google.com:443\r
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0\r
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r
\r
< 2024/01/31 16:58:27.400095  length=153 from=0 to=152
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r
Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.10.5\r
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2024 16:58:27 GMT\r
Proxy-Agent: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.10.5\r
\r
> 2024/01/31 16:58:27.470889  length=517 from=112 to=628
>>>> binary data <<<
```

With the following nginx config and by forcing access to http://google.com goes to the server it is as follows:

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    server_name google.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3129;
        proxy_set_header MyHeaded "SpecialValue";
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
root@3863da2d8f8a:~# curl http://google.com
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.3</center>
</body>
</html>
---------
> 2024/01/31 17:43:05.675299  length=132 from=0 to=131
GET / HTTP/1.0\r
MyHeaded: SpecialValue\r
Host: host.docker.internal:3129\r
Connection: close\r
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0\r
Accept: */*\r
\r
```

By adding the additional line from the question like the followings does not realy changes the outcome for me:

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    server_name google.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3129;
        proxy_set_header MyHeaded "SpecialValue";
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header Host google.com;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
root@3863da2d8f8a:~# curl http://google.com
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.3</center>
</body>
</html>
---------
> 2024/01/31 17:49:30.289464  length=117 from=0 to=116
GET / HTTP/1.0\r
MyHeaded: SpecialValue\r
Host: google.com\r
Connection: close\r
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0\r
Accept: */*\r
\r
```